# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name ejb/com not found in context "java:comp/env"

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, jndi

Error message is as mentioned in title. Below code snippet is used in various places across different project packages. ejb-jar.xml and binding files are defined properly. The main reason I am asking is I am not sure why it is working well in some places, but not the other.

```
Context context = (Context)initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
Object localObj = context.lookup("ejb/com/notification");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is usually better to use just one line:

```
Object localObj = context.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/com/notification");
```

and since you are using `java:comp/env` you must have ejb reference defined, either using deployment descriptor or annotation. For classes used in web module, it must be defined in `web.xml` (or EJB annotation in any servlet), for classes used from EJB components, it must be defined in each 'parent' EJB again either using `ejb-jar.xml` or annotation.

Comment: we are using ejb-jar.xml, I can see all the definitions are defined there, but still getting the same error.

Comment: @VictorWang Attach your ejb-jar.xml and describe in which components it works and in which it doesn't.